# Missing telephone number pad on Safari web app.

Tags: html, ios7, input, mobile-safari, ios8

I'm working in a html5 mobile app. I need only number keyboard or telephone pad but I have not lucky with that in ipad with iOS 7 neither ipad with iOS 8.

This is the code with which I'm trying

```
<input type="number"/>

<input type="number" pattern="\d*"/>

<input type="tel">
```

Always the same keyboard opens

[Default numeric keyboard.](https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRzTPn7lomqB2P_e5DS7efUaTySH8z8Zq8m3Da7L0cmhT7kfDzm2A)

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is:

```
<input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*">
```